# How to pass an array in to json

Tags: arrays, json

How to pass an array in to json.I am using ajax and json in jsp. 
please help

```
events: [                           
{ 
    title: title[i],
    start:start[i]
},
]
```

Comment: Please ask a more specific question

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to make your array to a JSON string. You can do like this

```
 var jsonString =  JSON.stringify(yourarray);
```

Hope this helps. In modern browsers, they include JSON as a standard object. if you want older browsers to work, then you need to include the js from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js